# Read excel file one line at a time matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, optimization

I have a big excel file and I'm trying to read it one line at a time. To do this I am using the excel COM object and writing

```
excelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
W = excellApp.workbooks.Open(f);
Sheet = W.Sheets.Item('1');
```

Now I used to do something like `Sheet.usedRange.value2` to get all the values from that particular sheet. But now I want to read one row at a time; how can I do this?

Looking into the code of `xlsread` I see they do this by calling a Range function, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: See: Microsoft's [Office Development documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161347.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In pure VBA (except that `Sheet` is protected keyword), it'd look something like this :

```
LastRow = Sheet.Range("A" & Sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(i, 1),Sheet.Cells(i,10)).Value2
Next i
```

So in Matlab, it'd probably be something like this :

```
excelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
W = excellApp.workbooks.Open(f);
Sheet = W.Sheets.Item('1');
LastRow = Sheet.Range("A" & Sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row;

For i = 1:LastRow
    Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(i, 1),Sheet.Cells(i,10)).Value2;
end
```